# Unable to use any commands in vim-taskpaper

Tags: vim, plugins

I'm a completely new vim user and my first foray into plugins is vim-taskpaper.

This is the plugin I'm using: https://github.com/cweagans/vim-taskpaper

The syntax highlighting works, but whenever I try to run a command, "/td" for example, I get this error: "E486: Pattern not found: td"

Here's what I've done so far:

- Installed the plugin and explicitly set my leader as '/'.

Here's my .vimrc file:

```
call plug#begin('~/.vim/plugged')
Plug 'cweagans/vim-taskpaper'
call plug#end()

let mapleader = "/"
```

- I've run `:PlugInstall` in vim and restarted it.
- I've tried setting mapleader to other characters but the result is the same.

Anyone know how to solve this?

Comment: Are you editing a file with the `.taskpaper` extension to begin with?

Comment: Yes, `my-tasks.taskpaper`. I also forgot to mention that I'm using a Mac. In case that has an impact.

Comment: I've fiddled with it some more and I think I've worked it out. I think my mistake was, being a vim noob, not realising that there's a narrow time window in which the leader acts as a leader and not a regular slash. I hesitated in typing in the commands for a second and therefore they weren't interpreted as commands.

Comment: I'll mess about with this some more until I'm positive that I've solved all my problems before I'll post an answer to the question. : )